# ImageJ JavaScript, how do I cycle through directories?

Tags: java, javascript, image, loops, imagej

I am trying to create a script that will cycle through directories and open an image and analyse it etc..

so I would like to convert something like the script below into a loop;

```
//sets the pixel height and width

height = 15; 
width = 15;

//navigates to the folder and opens the image

IJ.run("Raw...", "open=[C:\\Users\\Documents\\Ru\\simulations_Ru\\Batch1_sc\\1 Atoms\\15x15_stem_image00001_total_df_00001.bin] image=[64-bit Real] width=15 height=15 offset=0 number=1 gap=0");


imp = IJ.getImage();

//selects a region of interest I want to make measurements from

imp.setRoi(0, 0, width, height);


//makes the measurement

IJ.run(imp, "Measure", "");


//closes the image

imp.close();
```

What I'd like to know is how can I turn this into a loop (instead of having to type commands for each folder) so it iterates over the number of specific folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
height = 15; 
width = 15;

var cmds = //cmds is a shortage of commands
[
     "open=[C:\\Users\\Documents\\Ru\\simulations_Ru\\Batch1_sc\\1 Atoms\\15x15_stem_image00001_total_df_00001.bin] image=[64-bit Real] width=15 height=15 offset=0 number=1 gap=0",
     "another command",
     "and so on..."
];

for(var i in cmds)
{
  IJ.run("Raw...", cmds[i]);


  imp = IJ.getImage();
  imp.setRoi(0, 0, width, height);
  IJ.run(imp, "Measure", "");

  imp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How I read it, the question was more about finding out how to iterate over the files in a directory. I've been looking for this quite a while some months ago and found it difficult to get to the right piece of information, as most stuff about JavaScript is dealing with running inside a browser, and not having access to the "local" filesystem at all...

Anyway, in ImageJ this is possible with the following JavaScript code:

```
importClass(Packages.java.io.File);

var foo = File('/tmp/');
dirlist = foo.list();

for (var i = 0; i < dirlist.length; i++) {
    print(dirlist[i]);
}
```

So inside the "for" loop you could open the file, do you processing steps and write the result into a new file.